# Calling a function from Android Custom keyboard

Tags: android

I have created my own custom keyboard. I am planning to work on algorithms for natural language processing like `swype keyboard`. I have been able to make the keyboard with all the desired keys but, How do I call a function from the keyboard based on Button Press to process the input data.

EDIT

In `Keyboard.xml`

```
<Key android:codes="51" android:keyLabel="W" />
<Key android:codes="33" android:keyLabel="E" />
<Key android:codes="SOMETHING" android:keyLabel="Call_DETECTKEYPRESS" />
```

For all the keys and special keys that I need in my keyboard using codes from Android Documentation.

In `MyFunction.java`

```
public static List<String> DetectKeyPress(List<String> keysPressed){

//Custom Algorithm to process and predict possible words based on Natural Language Processing.
}
```

So if i hit the key labeled `Call_DETECTKEYPRESS` is there any way to call the Function `DetectKeyPress()` in `MyFunction.java`

Or it is not possible ? IF not possible how is `SWYPE keyboard` is able to process and predict the text.

Comment: What do you mean by "call a function from the keyboard?"

Comment: Basically I want my keyboard to suggest possible words based on what is typed. So my algorithm needs to be called each time a key is pressed. The function I refer to houses the Algorithm

Comment: Please provide some example code to illustrate what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Code-Guru Thanks for heads up. I have added some code. I hope this makes the Question more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You can set key and keycode in keyboard's xml layout file as this,

```
<Key android:codes="-202" android:keyLabel="DO SOMETHING"/>

public static final KEY_DO_SOMETHING = -202;
```

Then, you should implement your own keyboard controller class like this,

```
public class SoftKeyboard extends InputMethodService implement KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener
```

Overwrite onKeyDown or onKeyUp function,

```
@Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KEY_DO_SOMETHING:
        // do what you want to do here
    }
}
```

You can also look at the sample 'softKeyboard' app which provided in android's sdk.
For other complicated operation, like flick or swype, just do some mathematics with touch points.